# Perform SQL query parallel procesing on table with n sql statements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parallel-processing

I am running a cursor to generate automatically SQL statements to search a DB for a list of specific values. This will generate, for example, 180 queries stored in a SQL_QueryTable. Secondly, as seen below, I will use a cursor to fetch each statement from the SQL_QueryTable, execute the statement against a table with 150 million records, and ultimately store the results into a result table.

However, this works, but it takes a very long time. 
Looking for a suggestion to improve running time.

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Counter int = 1
DECLARE @TrackerID nvarchar(max)

DECLARE SQLQuery CURSOR

   FOR SELECT SQL_Query, TrackerID FROM SQL_QueryTable
OPEN SQLQuery

      FETCH NEXT FROM SQLQuery INTO @SQLQuery, @TrackerID

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                 PRINT @SQLQuery
                 PRINT @Counter

                 Insert Into Table_1 (column1, column2, column3, column4)
                 Exec(@SQLQuery)            --                     
                 Update Table_1
                 Set TrackerID = @TrackerID
                 where TrackerID is null

                SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
                FETCH NEXT FROM SQLQuery INTO @SQLQuery, @TrackerID
            END
Close SQLQuery
Deallocate SQLQuery
```

Comment: Are you certain the queries need to be automatically generated? If you can just write fewer queries that do what you need then parallelism will happen automatically (assuming the query planner thinks it will be faster). Parallelism may not be the problem - maybe you just need better indexes

Comment: depends on what your query is doing ...if your 180 query is processing one record, it will definitely be much faster to do it in one single query rather than using cursor

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, I need to generate the SQL statements automatically as I have different number of keywords I need to search for. Therefore, I store them in a table as a SQL statement, using one cursor, and then run a second cursor to execute and store the results.

Comment: Hi @Squirrel, the number of query statements change every time depending on what I am searching for. Can not execute one single query as would have to every time to write manually everything.

Comment: It's possible that this could be rewritten to not use pre-built SQL and cursors but it's impossible to tell base on the info. Are you doing this because you are dynamically generating field names? Can you ascertain whether new indexes will help?

Comment: I strongly believe that the slowness is due to the cursor loop and executing the query one at a time. You probably need to re-look into the entire process and see how to do it in different manner. As it is, i doubt there isn't much can be done here

Comment: Again... your comment "as I have different number of keywords I need to search for." doesn't make me believe you have to do it this way. A common performance mistake is to write things using cursors instead of a set based fashion. I suggest you explain your original issue as this seems like an x y problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: One option that's always worked well for me... instead of using the cursor to generate queries that directly target your tables and then executing the queries, use the loop to generate Agent jobs that execute the queries .. and start the jobs. By using dynamically built Agent jobs, each query will be given it's own connection/spid.

Comment: Your problem is that you build metadata around SQL queries and then execute them in a cursor. I would build stored procedures inside your cursor for each sql query you have, and then put them into ssis. So just add a name to your sql query and that would be the name of your SP. Then you can easily map it in SSIS where you can execute them paralelle. This will increase it fast. And if i wanna make it really dynamically, i would use a dispatcher in SSIS, to parelle it without building SP first.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of any standard optimization methods (indexes, optimized SELECT statement...) you query the table one time per single data you need to find. This multiplies the effort. You need a different approach here to speed things up.

A simple upgrade could be to search one time for a SET of variables. If for example your operator is (=) this is simple. Store the search variable data into a new assistant table and then build one statement for all stored variables using IN or INNER JOIN to get the filtered data. The more values you search for that way, the better the performance. If your values are stored on different columns then you can repeat for each column, because using OR will degrade performance significantly.

The operators will somewhat or hardly complicate things. It depends on your custom searches. The equal operator (=) is easy to handle. Range operators (lesser, greater, between) define a set on their own and are harder to combine. Same for LIKE operator plus the extra effort to search strings.

Concluding, if you search using (=) you can group the searches even if those are split on different columns. If you do not use other operators you are fine. If you use at low numbers, use the grouping for the majority and leave those complex searches the way they work now.